# Loading .ser files in ubuntu after they were serialized in windows

Tags: java, ubuntu

I wrote a GUI code (Java Eclipse) and compressed it to JAR.
The code loads data from .ser serialized file.
It loads fine when using windows but cannot recognize the .ser file when using ubuntu.
Now , after saving a new .ser in ubuntu , it works just fine but I need the old .ser file to work. any idea how can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a portable serialization format. In the Windows application, load the old ser file and save it in a format like JSON or XML. The Linux application then needs to load the new JSON / XML file instead of the ser.

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked! for others-with details : I changed the file extension to xml on windows, sent it to myself by mail , downloaded on the computer that has ubuntu, copied the xml file to the project workspace instead of the ser file and changed the code to read an xml file -  fileInput = new FileInputStream("file.xml") and ---- I have all my data!!! Thank you!